# 404 redirection do not occur and same page open via multiple url string in zen cart

Tags: php, .htaccess, zen-cart

I am using ultimate SEO URL with zen cart framework. My url structure is

```
http://www.domain.com/shipping-information

http://www.domain.com/category-name/product-name.html
```

The problem is if we put extra string with the above url it open the same page content rather than redirected to a 404 error page.

```
http://www.domain.com/shipping-information?jhssss

http://www.domain.com/category-name/product-name.html?777777#%
```

I can't figure out this issue and that's why google decrease our onpage ranking. Any one please figure out this issue and help me.